# Hash / Map that matches entries based on a subset of the key

Tags: java, data-structures, hash

Is there a Map implementation that can be used for determining whether a subset of some key exists in the map?

For example, consider a map keyed by a set of Strings:

```
Map<Set<String>, Object> map = new SomeExoticMap<>();
```

If we add a value:

```
Set<String> key = new HashSet<>();
key.add("1");
key.add("2");
map.put(key, "foo");
```

I'd like to determine whether an entry exists in the map for a subset of any entry's key:

```
Set<String> subset = new HashSet<>();
subset.add("2");
assert true == map.containsKey(subset);
```

I'd also like to learn all of the values that my key subset matched:

```
List<Object> matchedValues = map.subsetValues(subset);
assert matchedValues == Arrays.asList("foo");
```

Obviously this problem could be solved with a linear search, but that won't scale for my needs. Is there a Map-like data structure that can do this sort of thing? If not, how would one go about building one?

Comment: `containsKey` is going to call `equals` on your key. You'll need to override that and `hashcode` in HashSet<String>.

Comment: @deanosaur Not sure how to calculate the hash code though since the hash code of key and subset in the above example would be different, thus, containsKey would not always work, even if equals matched them based on a subset.

Comment: I don't think there's a good, general purpose algorithm for what you want to achieve. I would suggest using a hash map `String -> [(Set, Value)]` (key is mapped to all possible sets that contain it). Then for a query, pick an element randomly from the query set, look it up in the data structure and do a linear search from there. You can extend the concept to *k* randomly picked points from the subset and a k-dimensional query in your data structure

Comment: @NiklasB. I think you're on the right track - checking each individual element of the key one at a time. To be clear, the sort of structure you were thinking was: Map<String, Map<Set<String>, Object>> ?

Comment: More like `Map<String, List<Pair<Set<String>, Object> > >`, only that Java doesn't have pairs/tuples

Comment: Or if your key sets are small enough (<6 or so), you can just store all subsets in a hash table

Comment: If two entries having same subset then what will be the return value in this case for that subset key. for e.g `Map` contains 2 keys [1,2,3] and [1,2]. Now you try to get value from [2] then what will be the return value? There is no point of designing this type of `Map`.

Comment: @NiklasB. I think some variation of what you described is what we'll end up doing. I can't mark this thing as answered though since you didn't file it as an answer :)

Comment: Interesting how you have 3 deleted answers below... Anyway I probably won't write an answer, but glad to help